# how do I bootstrap 2 responsive thumbnail columns with equal height.?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[responsive columns like a thumbnail carousel, with the image on centre of the top border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mQdx.png)

I do not have a basic idea to how to create this using bootstrap. I basically need to know how to create responsive columns. I have designed my desired result in photoshop and provided a link. Kindly take a look on the image to provide me with a better solution.

Comment: Check answer may be it will help you.

Comment: @LokeshGupta you can now check the image to provide a better solution.

Comment: You can get it which i posted I am posting a working example

Answer (score 0):

You can user .row-eq-height class of bootstrap.
Reference Link  : http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

Comment: I already checked this, but I want to bring it like a thumbnail card with glyphicons on the centre of the top border and below that text contents.

Comment: @AshishVyas kindly check the question again for the expected result.